# exception: "The specified URL has an unsupported scheme. Only http and https URLs are supported"

Tags: ios, react-native

In ios only, I get this problem after triying to concatenate a URL from state like this:

```
    componentDidMount(){

    let unionUrl = this.props.datos.brand + " " + this.props.datos.name

    this.setState({ 
        busqueda: unionUrl
      })
}

Expo.WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync("https://www.example.com/search?query=" + this.state.busqueda)
```

the error thrown is this

[image: the error thrown is this], 
it seems like it's injecting an array, instead of a string(?)

I tried this method before in react and worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by surrounding the props like this:

```
const url = "http://example.com/search?query=" +`${this.props.datos.brand} ${this.props.datos.name}`
const urlOk = url.split(' ').join('+').toString()
await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(urlOk)
```

This solution seems to work both on android and ios, but is kind of a bummer, since the "`" character doesn't exist in my language's keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, this worked for me

```
  let query = textToSearch.replace(" ", "+");
  let url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + query;
  await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(url);
```

When you entered a phrase at Google search, every space is converted to a plus sign (+). You can see that after you hit enter and look at the generated URL in your browser. Similar to the answer above but with a little bit of context, if you are concatenating words use plus signs instead of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it similar problem by deleting the whitespaces in the parameters I sent in the url.